# Trying to animate the titleLabel of my custom UIButton located in a tableview cell fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

The code inside the custom button class is:

```
func animate() {
      let translationForTitle = CGAffineTransform(translationX: frame.height, y: 0)

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0.0,
                     usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
                     initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .curveEaseOut], animations: {
        titleLabel?.layer.setAffineTransform(translationForTitle)
      }, completion: nil)
}
```

The button is linked to an interface builder cell button.

What is supposed to happen is: the button titleLabel should move from the middle of the button to outside of the button under 3secs.

**What is actually happening:**
The titleLabel first *teleport* on the left side of the button and then scroll to the right side on the button.

any idea?

EDIT:
the cell containing the button animates to expand (change of height) with a tableview beginUpdate and endUpdate.

Comment: did you tried titleLabel?.transform = translationForTitle. and remove .beginFromCurrentState option?

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work

Comment: Then I suggest create button's snapshot, hide cell's button, add snapshot to tableView.superview at cell's button coordinate and then move with animation. This time you should animate frame change, not transform